# Can't change mac address, tried everything

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

I am really stuck. I am trying to change the MAC address of my adapter, but it never saves.

I already tried using things like *tmac* and editing the registry.

Also when I go into **Device Manager** and click *properties* of the network adapter, the "**Network address**" option is missing.

Please help me change it because I tried everything. Thank you.

I am trying to change the following:

Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter

Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2

Comment: What is it that you’re truly trying to accomplish? Maybe something like “changing the MAC address of my wireless network adapter”? Or “changing the BSSID of my Windows Hotspot feature”? // Also, why are you trying to do this? There may be better solutions.

Comment: My network adapter was banned on a game. I'm trying to change the mac address of the wireless network adapter.

Comment: That’s too sad. I very much doubt you’re banned based on your MAC address.

Comment: @Telekinesis They would have banned the MAC of your router's WAN port if it was done via MAC _(your local MAC wouldn't be exposed to WAN)_, but usually it's done by WAN IP or gamer tag.  Have you tried unplugging your modem and router for ~10min to initiate a new WAN IP being assigned _(unplug both for ~10min, plug modem in and allow it to fully boot, which takes 60 - 90s, then plug router back in)_

Comment: I checked the logs of the game, it's showing my original mac address being used by the wireless adapter.

Comment: @Telekinesis Inbound WAN traffic cannot see local MAC addresses, just as it can't see local RFC1918 address... all the game's servers are seeing is your router's WAN IP and MAC.  The only way WAN side traffic can see local MACs and IPs is if masquerading is disabled on the router _(it shouldn't be)_.  Your PC logs will show the local MAC and IP, possibly the WAN IP, but the router removes both when it sends traffic over WAN, replacing the local MAC with it's MAC and the local IP with it's WAN IP _(this is masquerading)_

Comment: @JW0914 The game server can’t see the router’s MAC address because it very certainly isn’t on the same network segment.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes custom MAC address must have certain prefix. Safest route is to try to reuse first 4--6 hexadecimal integers from original address, like `AB:CD:EF:__:__:__`.

This is likely caused by the address range assigned to manufacturer by IEEE. It seems that this web site may provide allowed ranges: https://www.ipchecktool.com/tool/macfinder If it will be down, you may try searching for `MAC address of vendor`.

Answer (score 0):

- **Network Connections** > Right-click **Network Adapter** > **Properties** - *Configure*

  - **Advanced** > **Property: Network Address** - *Value:* 
     OR 
     **Advanced** > **Property: MAC Address** - *Value:*

    - *Property name depends on the adapter*

Comment: Whether an option is available there is strictly dependent on the driver. There’s nothing with Intel wireless drivers.

Comment: I already tried that, I don't have those options.

Comment: @DanielB I wasn't aware the virtual drivers were Intel drivers. Telekinesis: Not sure how I missed that in your question... Are the virtual drivers Intel drivers, and if not, what installed them?

Comment: They’re not. They’re also not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Yes it is intel drivers, the name is Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V